# How is the îto solution calculated?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Currently I'm learning about SDE's. In my document there is a SDE. It is a stochastic BOD model:

$\begin{aligned} \frac{d B_{t}}{d t} &=-K_{1} B_{t}+s_{t}-B_{t} \sigma N_{t} \\ B_{t_{0}} &=B_{0} \end{aligned}$

This is written in terms of a Wiener process as:

$d B_{t}=\left(-K_{1} B_{t}+s_{t}\right) d t-B_{t} \sigma d W_{t}$

$B_{t_{0}}=B_{0}$

From this the Îto formulation is given.

The explaination is:

"since the white noise process in this stochastic model is a mathematical approximation of a noise
process with a relatively short correlation scale, this SDE has to be interpreted in the
Stratonovitch sense. since the Euler scheme (14) can only be used for İto equations, the model
above is first rewritten as an Ito SDE:"

(14):$X_{t}+f\left(X_{t}, t\right) \Delta t+g\left(X_{t}, t\right)\left(W_{t+\Delta t}-W_{t}\right)$

Ito formulation:

\begin{array}{l}
d B_{t}=\left(-K_{1} B_{t}+s_{t}+\frac{1}{2} B_{t} \sigma^{2}\right) d t-B_{t} \sigma d W_{t} \\
B_{t_{0}}=B_{0}
\end{array}

My question is:

How should I've known to interpretate the SDE as Stratonovitch?

Comment: while waiting for the answer, would you mind sharing me the name of your document so that if there is no answer in the future, I can try to formulate a suitable answer for you ?

Comment: The name is "course notes" and it is not a famous document. I uploaded it online and I'll share the link. It would be really great if you could help me. The relevant page is 22/39
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1--kenPRdC5YLRdm5A18vTvB6PxCLfbWS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks (comment too short)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**
If your SDE is derived directly from a physic equation involving the derivative term  $\frac{d}{dt}$( or not as often, $\frac{d}{dx}$ ), it is kinda sure that your SDE is in Stratonovitch sense.

**Reference**

In fact, the choice is casewise, depends largely on the pragmatic aspect of the choice and also the interpretation of the phenomenon through that SDE. More discussion here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/245692/it%C3%B4-or-stratonovich-calculus-which-one-is-more-relevant-from-the-point-of-view